# How to get common things between two users in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have a requirement to count common liked items of two users. How can i do this in spring data mongodb.

Suppose user1 likes item a ,user2 likes item a,then common item between these users is 1. So,same structure  of item like/dislike here,so how to get this item by mongodb query.

My domain design looks like

```
public class UserItemHistory {

    long userId;
    long itemId;
    int status   // status will be 1 if user likes item

}
```

Data structure will be

```
{
   user_id:1,
   item_id:2,
   status:1

}

{
   user_id:2,
   item_id:2,
   status:1

}
```

Comment: This does not really explain a lot. Is the `itemId` unique to each user so that it is never listed more than once per `userId`? Are the same `itemId` values kept for all users? Making it possible to indentify that two users share the same "like" status on the `itemId`?

Comment: yes i have updated question,please check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want this aggregation pipeline with the `.aggregate()` method. In short you provide the common users to match and ask for items with a "liked" status. Then you "group by" the "itemId" and count the number of matches between the two users. Finally you filter this to all items "having" a count that is "greater than" 1 as this indicates the same item was present for both users.

As an aggregation pipeline, that is three simple steps, `$match` then `$group` to count then `$match` again on the count values:

```
  { "$match": {
    "userId": { "$in": [1,2] },
    "status": 1
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$itemId",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } } }
```

Which can be written with helpers under spring mongo like this:

```
    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            match(
                    Criteria.where("userId").in(Arrays.asList(1, 2))
                            .and("status").is(1)
            ),

            group("itemId").count().as("count"),

            match(Criteria.where("count").gt(1))

    );
```

Which provides the pipeline to be run with `.aggregate()` against the class or collection as you choose.

Comment: Can i use $lookup with it,it is providing me item_id with count . I want to fetch data using item_id from another collection "items". One way is i can do with second query but it's good if it can possible with it.

Comment: @PrabjotSingh [Ask a new Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).That's how it works here. We answer the question you ask then it's done. When you have a new question to ask ( like that ) then you post a new question. Also understand that `$lookup` is essentially running another query, albeit on the server, and that is going to add significant cost. So the sort of "self join" pattern often abused in SQL  is generally avoided and "should" be avoided by better design.